# Audio not working when testing iOS app on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm making an iOS app and it has a few audio (.mp3) files in it. I have copied the files to the project itself. When I test on the simulator, everything works. However, when I test the app on my iPhone, the audio doesn't play. Anyway to fix this?

Here are snippets of my code relating to the audio:

`var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()`

In my viewDidLoad() function, I have the following code:

```
// address of the music file.
let music = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ding1", ofType: "mp3")
// copy this syntax, it tells the compiler what to do when action is received
do {
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: music! ))
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    }
catch{
    print(error)
    }
```

In order to play the sound, I use this: `audioPlayer.play()`

Comment: Is your iPhone in silent (vibration) mode?

Comment: Should've checked that before posting, thanks!

Comment: :-D There some AVAudioSession that will override this behavior.